# How to reduce gap between two display:inline items?

Tags: css

How to reduce gap between two display:inline items?

gap is showing on all browser?

```
ul.tabs li {
display:inline;
margin:0 padding:0;}
```

[alt text http://img167.imageshack.us/img167/7283/pruebank5.gif](http://img167.imageshack.us/img167/7283/pruebank5.gif)

I can fix the problem using float:left in the LI elements but I need
to understand why it's happening.

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear. I don't see that there has to be a gap: http://jsbin.com/egavo3 please provide us with some code to reproduce your problem

Comment: Alternatively, analyze the elements with Firebug's "Layout" tool, it should show you what is responsible for the gap. Are you sure it's not just white spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have whitespace between your inline elements. `float: left` fixes the problem, because floating implicitely converts the element to a block element, regardless of `display: inline`.

And you need a `;` between `margin:0` and `padding: 0`.

Answer (score 3):

> ... but I need to understand why it's happening.

You may have whitespace or new lines between your inline elements.

---

For further reading, you may want to check out the following Stack Overflow post:

- [Best way to manage whitespace between inline list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the word-spacing CSS property to less than 1em.