# Spaces between inline list items when code is on separate lines

Tags: html, css

If I code inline list items on separate lines of code there is a space inserted between them.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening with coding all of the list items on the same line of code?

```
<li>123</li>
<li>456</li>
```

creates the following which I don't want

**123 456**

```
<li>123</li><li>456</li>
```

creates the following which i do want

**123456**

thanks

Comment: did you try using 'li {display:block}'? maybe you should include some code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you 
use CSS `display: inline` to inline your list items?

`display: inline` does exactly that: it converts your new line in your source code to a space character. You have two options now:

1. Either you write all your `<li>` items in one line, then display: inline will actually make your list items behave like you want (no space in-between) - I have set up an example for you here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/NxrQ9/.
2. Or instead of inlining your elements you just go with `display:block` and `float: left`.

Comment: Also see this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items

Comment: float:left is the one I was looking for. Thanks... no need to display:block though.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting padding and margin to 0:

```
#ul_id li{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
```