# Unknown space between list item

Tags: css, html

I am designing a simple joomla template. When I came to a very weird problem. Although, I didn't gave any margin or padding, some spaces are appearing between the list items.

Here is a link to the fiddle. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/N4FZD/)

Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Firebug shows nothings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to manage whitespace between inline list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the joomla scenario. But this is default way the inline-blocks behave. They add about 4px margin to the right, automatically.

A quick fix of this is applying `float:left` to the list items

But, a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items) has been asked already and the answerer has provided with the better solution. i.e. closing and starting the `li`'s in a same line

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li><li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li><li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li><li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Furthermore, [this](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) might be worth reading as well.

Comment: Correct way would be to avoid such pattern, if it bothers you.

Comment: Adding a <div> inside <li> is not a good practice and it won't even support viewport

Answer (score 0):

before building a site i suggest to use reset css. it avoide all browser issue and reset all element

this even fix your issue

Comment: check this link


http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/


<code>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css"> </code>

it will reset all your style. any resolve max your browser issue