# Small amount of space in nav bar items - layout issue

Tags: css

I fond that when inspecting my navigation items such as `<a class="nav_anchor">` in firebug and also when I hover over them, there is an estimate of a 5 pixel spacing on the right of each navigation item.

I have had little success in working out what is causing this to happen within the navigation, any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is the link: http://www.the-session.co.uk/pros/

Perhaps this image can help show the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline & inline-block elements are affected by any white-space in your HTML. This is causing the small gap between each list-item. You can either comment the space out, or you can manually delete it. You can also `float: left;` each `<li>` or to give a negative left-margin by a few px

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Answer (score 1):

**Here's your CSS after fix**

```
#main_menu {
    padding: 7px 10px 7px 20px;
    background-color: #6bb8c7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6bb8c7, #6cadde);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6bb8c7), to(#6cadde));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6bb8c7, #6cadde);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6bb8c7, #6cadde);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #6bb8c7, #6cadde);
    height: 50px;
}
.menu_item, .menu_item_first {
    display:inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
}
a.nav_anchor {
    padding: 7px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    float: left;
}
```

**Simply you need to add height to the menu div container and float:left to li and the anchor.**