# space between divs in html5 document

Tags: css

my question is simple. how can i remove the space between div tags?

this is my html document:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div>option 1</div>
    <div>option 2</div>
    <div>option 3</div>
    <div>option 4</div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
div.nav {
    border:1px solid;
}

div.nav > div {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:0
}
```

here is the fiddle where you can see this
http://jsfiddle.net/dmsf/7Szjw/3/

the doctime is html5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to manage whitespace between inline list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="nav">
    <div>option 1</div><div>option 2</div><div>option 3</div><div>option 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add float: left; to div.nav > div like this:

```
div.nav {
    border:1px solid;
}

div.nav > div {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: While floating works, you no longer need `display:inline-block` and you should also clear the float afterwards so that the containing div doesn't collapse. http://jsfiddle.net/DyKFb/