# Spacing between two <li> elements

Tags: html, css

I've written the folloning code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

and styles:

```
list-style-type: none;
padding: 5px;
display: inline;
background-color: #A9A9A9;
```

But i have spacing between two `li` elements like the following:

[image]

How can I remove this spacing?

Comment: have you tried `margin: 0;`?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ This url clearly explain how to remove space in between them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to manage whitespace between inline list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Comment: just add float:left in your css

Answer (score 3):

By put them inline

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li><li>text</li>
</ul>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myMZT/)

Answer (score 3):

If you `float` your `li` items, it should remove the margin between `li` output.

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #A9A9A9;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `display: block;` when you use `float` also you haven't cleared them

Comment: to clear the float you need to put a class with `clear:both` on the end. `<div class="clear"></div>` or `<div style="clear:both"></div>` :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two common ways to avoid the space:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  one</li><li> <!-- use this to avoid the linebreak -->
  two</li><li>
  three</li>
</ul>
```

---

Or you can use Comments:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!-- Comments so there is no white-space
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

---

You can check it in this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNQE9/5/)

You get the space because there is `some space between the elements`. 
(`Tabs, Newline count as space` ). With this Minimized HTML it should work :)

---

You can read more about it here [**Examples at CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

> **Just Add float:left in your Css**

```
ul li {
   background-color: #A9A9A9;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2M7ME/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways as mentioned above few of them..however you can achieve with another method. using `font-size:0`

```
ul
{font-size:0; /*This will remove the space totally*/
list-style-type: none;
} 

li{
padding: 5px;
display: inline;
background-color: #A9A9A9;
font-size:16px; /*This is important line so the font come again in same shape*/
}
```

Here is the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/genodima/1/)***.

Comment: If my example works for you. Then you may close this question by accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

try floats and use `list-style-type` for `ul`:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  padding: 5px;
  float:left;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}
```