# Whitespace around img tags causes different layouts

Tags: jquery, html, css, whitespace

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q4fW9/3/

I have two divs containing the exact same HTML.  The only difference is the formatting - one is all on one line while the other is on multiple lines.  The question here is why do they display differently?  I tested it in both IE and Chrome and saw the same thing.

So the actual issue I'm having is that one of them is created on page load (the properly formatted one) and the other is built through jQuery.  So how do I get the jQuery insert to display the same way?

```
<div><div><img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" /><img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" /></div></div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" />
        <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
img.navButton {
    margin: 0 -4px;
}
```

**EDIT: To clarify the second part of the question: How do I use jQuery to produce the html in the second div?  The one that has the spaces between the images.**

Comment: `img.navButton { float:left; margin: 0 -4px; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to manage whitespace between inline list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Comment: Also, JQuery doens't include whitespace when adding HTML (AFAIK)...hence the difference.

Comment: img is inline tag. Please read about the difference of the inline and block elements to prevent asking these questions at future

Comment: @AlexPrinceton Please read the entire question to prevent half-answers.

Comment: @Paulie_D so the answer to the jQuery part is that you simply can't generate the clean-looking html using jQuery?

Comment: @Andrew TBH, I'm no JS./JQ expert but I saw that same issue in another SO Q/A.

Comment: It's probably more reliable to style them the same, regardless of whitespace.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti Absolutely.  The problem is that if I change the CSS, it affects every page, while the jQuery insert is literally on one page, so there's less risk to fix that.

Comment: Perhaps show us your Jquery? Can you add whitesapce to that?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah I should have posted that.  You're right, you can add whitespace to it.  I think I tried it at one point and thought it wasn't working because I was using prepend and got the order screwed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use jQuery to add with whitespace, you only really need one space to get the effect, so you could do this (assumes there's a wrapper with class 'imgs'):

```
$(".imgs").append('<div> <div> <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" /> <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" /> </div> </div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4fW9/8/

If you want that *exact* whitespace, you can do it like this:

```
$(".imgs").append('<div>\n\t<div>\n\t\t<img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" />\n\t\t<img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" />\n\t</div>\n</div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4fW9/9/

**(Note that this is only one way to do this.  There are dozens of ways, but the main idea is that you're setting the HTML string.  You could pretty easily do the same thing in plain old javascript using `innerHTML`)**

Comment: I think we have a winner.  I had appended the images separately, and assumed jQuery would make it pretty for me (or at least that whitespace wouldn't matter).  I guess I have to keep in mind it's basically string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Becausewouldyoubehappyreadingtextlikethis?Idon'tthinkso.

Spaces exist to space things out. If you don't want spaces, don't put spaces there! Personally, I minify HTML on-the-fly by stripping out newlines and tabs from the response before sending (but it has to be aware of where whitespace is meaningful, such as in `white-space:pre-wrap` elements, or `<pre>` tags). It helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the top div you don't have a space between your IMG tags.

In the bottom div you have a space between your IMG tags.

Images are by default display:inline.  Thats why you see the discrpeancy.

Improve your formatting to see the difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/q4fW9/7/

```
<div class="con">
    <div>
        <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" />
        <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" />
    </div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div class="con">
    <div>
        <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" /><img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" />
    </div>
</div>

.con { overflow:hidden; }
img { float:left; }
```

Comment: Great, but I'm using jQuery to create the one without spaces.  How do I change that?

Comment: One way to do that is to float your images like @mdesdev mentioned in the OP comments.  See updated code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

There is white space between those two image tags. They are inline elements. You can float your images if you would like to remove the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the surrounding div, and set the `font-size` to 0, or (as mdesdev pointed out in the comments) float the images.

*If you use the `font-size` approach, be careful about descendants that use `em` for their font size.

http://jsfiddle.net/q4fW9/5/

HTML:

```
<div><div class="icons"><img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" /><img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" /></div></div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div>
    <div class="icons">
        <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-first.gif" class="navButton" />
        <img src="http://argrunner.com/images/page-prev.gif" class="navButton" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icons {
    font-size: 0;
}
```