# CSS stretching child elements across parent element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get some list items to stretch across a list

This is the relevant code

```
#navbar ul
{   
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar li
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

Here's what it normally looks like:
[image]

But sometimes when I leave the page and come back later (not after reloading) this happens:
[image]
Setting the individual item width to 33.3% makes it one pixel short and making it 33.333% makes the problem worse...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to manage whitespace between inline list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Comment: <non-constructive comment>I haven't seen a website under construction image like that since around about the year 2000. Well done!</non-constructive comment>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily achieve this layout using css tables instead. Widely supported and semantically sound.

```css
#navbar ul {   
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed; /* makes all cells equal width */
}
#navbar li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kBnrz/1/

Comment: I like your answer but miss a text-align:center; for the li like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mmw29/

Comment: @caramba I left it out on purpose, along with color, margins etc, to keep the essential point clear ;)

Comment: This worked but for some reason I had to change the width to 96.8%... Thanks

Comment: @Miro Check the demo I posted, you will probably need to remove some native (user agent default) margins on the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

**remove padding of parent of "ul"**

Answer (score 1):

Just fake it:

```
#navbar ul li{
   width:33%;
}

#navbar ul li:last-child{
   width:34%;
}
```

Also include this style:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }
```

ref: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion:

@Miro try  **[CSS Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-css-flexbox-1-20140325/)** layout, it will help you, but it works only in modern browsers.

### CSS Flexbox

The CSS Flexible Box Layout Model, or **"flexbox"**, is one of the specification in CSS3. *`It provides for the arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements behave predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen sizes and different display devices`*. For many applications, the flexible box model provides an improvement over the block model *`in that it does not use floats, nor do the flex container's margins collapse with the margins of its contents`.*

Here is one example

### Html

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

### StyleSheet

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.box div.A {
    order:1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: auto;
}

.box div.B {
    order:2;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: auto;
}

.box div.C {
    order:2;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: auto;
}
```

Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Js6/)</kbd>**

This [Link](http://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/) will help you.

Comment: Flexbox is pretty neat :) I can't wait till the support is a bit more mature. http://caniuse.com/flexbox