# User Agent Stylesheets - Unwanted margin and no override works

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overriding

First of all, my testing code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            ul, li {
                margin: 0 !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }

            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            li {
                display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid red;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Very simple code !
But in Chrome, my 'li' have a margin between us. That's my problem : i dont want this marge !

A screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Uyu.jpg

I made some try without success :

- i tried with a normalize
- i tried with a reset
- i tried with and without the '!important' param

90% of related post talk about a simple 'margin' and 'padding' override but no one works.

I have this output with Chrome, Firefox and Safari, all lastest version.
I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks.
I'm using lastest MAMP too.

All my hope is in ur expertise ;) Thanks for reading, and helping i guess :) ;)

Comment: So you don't want any space in between the list items? Like you literally want the text touching one another? Because the space in between them is a space generated to separate list items..

Comment: You could always just use negative margin like so: http://jsfiddle.net/4px7s/

Comment: Thanks for negative margin hacks ;) I'm learning web development atm :) I tested with 'div' and inner 'div' in place of 'ul' and 'li', i have the same output. 'div' have the same style from User Agent than 'ul'/'li' ?

Comment: Just put your li's one after another like this: `<li>Test 1</li><li>Test 2</li><li>Test 3</li>`. Currently, there is a whitespace in between them. There are other ways to solve it, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **KonradDzwinel** for your solution :

> Just put your li's one after another like this:
>   `<li>Test 1</li><li>Test 2</li><li>Test 3</li>`
>   Currently, there is a whitespace in between them. There are other ways to solve it, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items).

Thanks a lot for your answer (**BuddhistBeast** too)