# Unwanted padding around buttons. CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, padding

Good evening. I needed help regarding CSS. I know this issue has been solved a number of times, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work for my program.
This script is to design an 8x8 board, with the cells on the boards being one of 8 distinct colors. So what I intended to do was to define a div, centred in a black background. Within this div would be my board. Since 8 cells are needed lengthwise and breadthwise, I set the respective attributes of width and height of the buttons, to 12.5%,ie, (100/8)% I have NOT specified any explicit padding, but still all buttons are associated by some(mainly on the right).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner
/*Recommended fix. But not working*/

{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.c1 {
  /*For coloring the buttons*/
  background-color: #cdaf95;
}
/*Here is the code for classes c2 -c7*/

.c8 {
  background-color: #5e2612;
}
.col1 {
  /*For defining the size of the buttons.*/
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 12.5%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
/*Here is code for classes col2-col7*/

.col8 {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 12.5%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
/*Board is the id of the division*/

#board {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="black">
  <style>
  </style>
  <div id="board">
    <button class="col1 c1"></button>
    <button class="col2 c1"></button>
    <button class="col3 c1"></button>
    <button class="col4 c1"></button>
    <button class="col5 c1"></button>
    <button class="col6 c1"></button>
    <button class="col7 c1"></button>
    <button class="col8 c1"></button>
    <button class="col1 c2"></button>
    <button class="col2 c2"></button>
    <!--And so on upto c8. Thats a total of 64 buttons forming an 8x8 board-->
    <button class="col7 c8"></button>
    <button class="col8 c8"></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any help in this manner would be greatly appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Are buttons inline elements? Might need to make them block or remove the white space around them

Comment: Share a working example. The code you share is fine, no paddings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to manage whitespace between inline list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241512/best-way-to-manage-whitespace-between-inline-list-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your html like this:

```
<body bgcolor="black">
  <div id="board">
<button class="col1 c1"></button><button class="col2 c1"><!--
--></button><!--
--><button class="col3 c1"></button><!--
--><button class="col4 c1"></button><!--
--><button class="col5 c1"></button><!--
--><button class="col6 c1"></button><!--
--><button class="col7 c1"></button><!--
--><button class="col8 c1"></button><!--
--><button class="col1 c2"></button><!--
--><button class="col2 c2"></button><!--
--><button class="col7 c8"></button><!--
--><button class="col8 c8"></button>
  </div>
</body>
```

just add

```
<!-- -->
```

between the

```
<button></button>
```

Make sure that is like this

```
<button></button><!-- --><button></button>
```

not

```
<button></button>  <!-- --><button></button>
<button></button><!-- -->   <button></button>
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/4vn4pv18/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to remove paddings on all items

```
*{    
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work. The padding on the right doesn't go.

Comment: Provide a fiddle and I could be of more help

Comment: Umm what is a fiddle?

Comment: As @Joseph said, the problem is not padding, just spaces. Remove the spaces between the buttons. Here. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/bcknsy68/1/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```js
/* just instead of writing 64 tags in a single row */
document.body.onload = function() {
  var out = '';
  for(var i=1; i<=8; i++)
for(var j=1; j<=8; j++)
  out += '<button class="col'+j+' c'+i+'"></button>';
  document.getElementById('board').innerHTML = out;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
button {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 12.5%;
  /* make sure that padding/border doesn't add up to dimensions */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* remove vertical spaces between lines */
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner
/*really needed and working*/
{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.c1 {
  /*For coloring the buttons*/
  background-color: #cdaf95;
}
/*Here is the code for classes c2 -c7*/

.c8 {
  background-color: #5e2612;
}
.col1 {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
/*Here is code for classes col2-col7*/

.col8 {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
/*Board is the id of the division*/

#board {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  /* make minimum height of lines of buttons as small as possible */
  line-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="black">
  <style>
  </style>
  <div id="board">
  </div>
</body>
```

The main trick is to remove inter-tag whitespace characters, including line breaks (as already mentioned) and to make the default line height less the height of the buttons (since they behave as *inline*-block elements, they can't make the line lower than its default height, only higher).

But wouldn't it be better to use Flexbox for this layout?